# How to Open my App during a call?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want my app to open whenever the user makes a call. I am able to know that call has started but cant open my app. Is there any way i can do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you tried so far?(I'm not a downvoter)

Comment: just open your desired activity where you are detecting call.

Comment: I am using  a listner to know when a call is placed, but i am unable to open my app @Amy

Answer (score 2):

When you know that a call has started, use your package name / class directly, for example to create a new intent to call the twidroid program you'd use the following[link text](http://snipplr.com/view/10688/use-twidroids-public-intent-to-send-twitter-messages-from-your-own--android-application/):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.twidroid.SendTweet");
```

You'd probably want to put a try/catch around for a ActivityNotFoundException for when the application is not installed.

Comment: How do you I has got this Error?